# Path to Pages Resolves to Archive instead of Actual Content

Tags: permalinks, pages, archives

When I upgraded to 3.4.1, the root level pages (ones that I had before, and any page I have afterwards) do not resolve to the actual page. No matter the name (so i don't think there is a slug issue), they all show only the archives. This surprisingly does not impact the child pages of these root pages. Just the top level.

I have tried disabling the plugins, no help. The only thing I have found to remotely "fix" the problem is switching the permalink structure from /%category%/%postname%/ to default.

Even if I explicitly type the url http://joshua.hailpern.com/?p=xxx, it shows the archive page, not the page content (but only for root pages)

Please help.